# Data conversion between int and char

Tags: c++

I am studying for a C++ test, I have not been able to solve this:

I have data in a int* and I want to print it out to a char*

I thought I could do it the following way:

```
// pOutputString is of type char*
// pIntegers is of type int*

int pos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< SIZE; i++)
{
  pOutputString[pos] = char(pIntegers[i]); 
  pos++;
}
```

if I iterate over pOutputString with iostream, I should get the 
tring representation (so 11 will turn into "11").

As part of this homework, I'm not allowed to use any third-party libs.  If I want something, I must do it myself.

Thanks.

Edit:  You can see the entire code in IDEone: http://ideone.com/nKXpg

Comment: What is `pOutputString`? What is `pIntegers`? What is `SIZE`? What's the bigger picture?

Comment: Are the standard libraries allowed, or can you only use the C++ language?

Comment: What do you mean?  An `int *` should print the same as a `char *` on all commonly used architectures.  Do you want to print out the character representation (so `11` would turn into `"11"`)?  Do you want to print the separate bytes of an `int`?

Comment: pOutputString is char*
pIntegers is a int*

All that I want to do is print the pOutputString, which should contain the char representation of the integers in pInteger.

I do not knw if the standard library is allowed.  I'm sending my professor an Email.  For now I am assuming it is not.

Comment: @Juan: Even with that code, you still haven't said anything about how the input numbers relate to the output string. Even the example is ambiguous: `so 11 will turn into "11"` - is the input eleven or an array of two ones?

Comment: If the input is {1,2,10} then the output should be {"1","2","10"}

Comment: Juan: I'm not sure if your output is supposed to be `"1210"` or `"1,2,10"`, but I don't think `{"1","2","10"}` is one of the options.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the standard library is not third-party, so use that.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

ostringstream s;
for (int i = 0; i< SIZE; i++) {
    s << ( i? ", " : "" ) << pIntegers[i];
}
strcpy( pOutputString, s.str().c_str() );
```

There was a header `<strstream>` and class `ostrsream` that could do this without `strcpy`, but it's been deprecated as it was too easy to allow overflow.

(I'm making an assumption here about the input and output data formats, but iostreams probably has a way to format as you want.)

Comment: The exercise I'm doing says that I must use pIntegers as input and pOutputString as output, where pIntegers is of type int* and pOutputString is of type char*.  But I understand your answer and your comment regarding iostream formatting

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you have an array of integer and that you want to print the character representation of these integers (assuming it is possible), you could try something like :

```
// int in[SIZE] is given
char out[SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  out[i] = static_cast<char>(in[i]);
}
std::cout << out;
```

By the way it is not a conversion between `int*` and `char*` but between `int` and `char`.

The following code does exactly that:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int in[] = {50,55,35};
  char out[3];
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    out[i] = static_cast<char>(in[i]);
  }
  std::cout << out << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there no bigger picture? Without knowing how `pOutputString` is defined, this question can't be safely answered. A `char *pOutputString` is only enough to hold **one** string representation of an integer (unless you want the string representations concatenated in one big string).

If you have a `char** OutputStrings` (or, better, `char* OutputStrings[]`), you can iterate over that just like you iterate over your pIntegers - keep in mind that each `OutputStrings[i]` needs to have memory allocated to it! (This is why we use `std::vector` and `std::string` in real-life code).

Is the real purpose of the exercise to write your own "integer to string representation" (Ie, your own [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/)) function? If so, it's not too bad - play around with division, modulus, and adding ascii '0' :)

## EDIT

Assuming you don't need to store the converted strings anywhere, have a look at the following program structure:

```
void IntToString(char* output, int input)
{
    // do div/mod/add-char('0') magic here, terminate buffer with \0 .
}
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    int a[SIZE] = { /* put your contents here */ };
    char outstring[12];
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        IntToString(outString, a[i]);
        cout << outstring << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with more information.  You can see the code I've written so far here: http://ideone.com/nKXpg

Comment: The purpose of the exercise is to transverse a matrix in clockwise order and print out the content of the matrix in such order.

Comment: I'm assuming you have to write your own "int to string" conversion, otherwise you could simply printf or cout each integer... if you don't need the strings stored but only printed, you only need IntToString(char *output, int input), and you can "cout << outputbuffer;"

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought of itoa but looks like it is a non-standard function. A good first "C-ish?" attempt could be (Standard C library is not a third party lib).

```
int main(){
    char buf[sizeof(int)*3 + 2];
    int x = 66;

    sprintf(buf, "%d", x);
     cout << buf;
}
```

If the idea is to completely hand-code without any library functions, others have already provided brilliant answers.

**EDIT 2**
Here is another quick and dirty implementation (with dirty alternates for strlen and strrev)

```
int main(){
    char buf[sizeof(int)*3 + 2] = {};

    int x = 0;
    int q = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int index = 0;

    cin >> x;
    if(0 == x) 
        buf[index++] = 48;
    else{
        while(x){
            q = x / 10;
            r = x % 10;
            buf[index++] = r + 48;
            x /= 10;
        }
    }

    char *p = buf;
    size_t len = 0;

     // e.g. for 255, the buffer now has 552, need to reverse it
     // dirty replacement for strlen
    while(*p++) len++;
    len--;

     // dirty reversing logic for strrev
    for(size_t s = 0; s <= len/2; s++){
        char t = buf[s];
        buf[s] = buf[len-s];
        buf[len-s] = t;
    }
    cout << buf;
}
```